# Adding a different domain to existing Wordpress site

Tags: forms, links, domain, language, customization

I haven't really found a question covering this topic and I'm sure that's because I don't know exactly how to word it.

The problem is the following: My boss has recently overtaken the Swiss branch of a small Argentinian wine company that sells wines through their website. Site looks like this so far with an English and Spanish option (as an example):

> www.wine-argentina.com/eng

What he wants is a domain like

> www.wine-argentina.ch (still needs to be bought)

which is supposed to point to the original domain but this time in German (like www.wine-argentina.com/ger). This German version is for the Swiss clients and is also supposed to include a simple form so that the Swiss clients can order wine.

I'm supposed to get into contact with their webmaster but I first wanna understand a few basics.

What is the best way to go about this? How can a domain like www.wine-argentina.ch be used in WP so that it points to some other domain like "www.wine-argentina.com/ger"?

Comment: You wouldn't really be using the new domain in WP - basically you would set up a redirect in `www.wine-argentina.ch` that would send everyone who hits that URL to `www.wine-argentina.com/ger`.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. It helps a lot. I'm guessing the simplest way would be then to ask the webmaster of the original site to construct a German site with a order form and then on our side to buy the swiss domain and directly link it to the German site constructed by the webmaster.

Comment: You'll probably want to set the original site up as a MultiSite or use one of the translation plugins. You'll need to deal with tags to tell search engines which site is in which language and which region, so that you don't run up against duplicate content issues.